# postgres: get earliest and latest record per day in linear time

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table with columns. one of them is timestamp. there is an index on that timestamp. is there a efficient query (big data) that let's me get min and max row for each day? the result must include all other columns.

or the only way is to do nested queries? sth like:

```
select * from 
   (select min(timestamp),max(timestamp) from table
   group by day)
where timestamp in (min, max)
```

or write my own custom postgres aggragation?

Comment: Either twice NOT  EXISTS(), or twice RANK(). (and don't name your columns `timestamp` or your table `table`)

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? (such as an id/identity column)

Comment: i can have if it's needed. i can define the table

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on `(timestamp::date, timestamp)` and then try:

```
select timestamp::date, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from t
group by timestamp::date;
```

I think that will use the index.

If you need all the columns, try having two indexes:

- `(timestamp::date, timestamp)`
- `(timestamp::date, timestamp desc)`

Then do:

```
(select distinct on (timestamp::date) t.*
 from t
 order by timestamp::date, timestamp asc
) union all
(select distinct on (timestamp::date) t.*
 from t
 order by timestamp::date, timestamp desc
)
```

Comment: but i need all the columns. and this will return only the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to your subquery:

```
select t.*
from table t
inner join (
  select min(timestamp) mint, max(timestamp) maxt 
  from table 
  group by timestamp::date
) g on (g.mint = t.timestamp or g.maxt = t.timestamp)
```

**Edit**:
If there is a unique column like `id` then:

```
with cte as (
  select t.*
  from table t
  inner join (
    select min(timestamp) mint, max(timestamp) maxt 
    from table 
    group by timestamp::date
  ) g on (g.mint = t.timestamp or g.maxt = t.timestamp)
)
select t.* from cte t
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where id < t.id and (mint = t.mint or maxt = t.maxt)
)
```

Comment: if we there are multiple records with the same timestamp, this will return all of them. is there any way get only one min and one max per day? doesn't matter which one

Comment: Which row would that be? On what condition? You can't just pick a random row. Is there a unique column. Because maybe this can be done by lacing the above code as a subquery in another query.

Comment: 'doesn't matter which one'. if there are many rows with max / min timestamp for specific day, i need to pick any one of them. it can be first, last, whichever

Comment: i define the table so there can be if needed

Answer (score 0):

Using not exists():

---

```
select *
from ztable t0
where not exists (
        select * from ztable t1
        WHERE t1.ztimestamp::date = t0.ztimestamp::date
        AND t1.ztimestamp < t0.ztimestamp
        )
or not exists (
        select * from ztable t2
        WHERE t2.ztimestamp::date = t0.ztimestamp::date
        AND t2.ztimestamp > t0.ztimestamp
        )
        ;
```

---

,or, using window functions:

---

```
select t0.*
from ztable t0
JOIN ( select timestamp
        , row_number()OVER (GROUP BY ztimestamp::date ORDER BY ztimestamp ASC) AS rn1
        , row_number()OVER (GROUP BY ztimestamp::date ORDER BY ztimestamp DESC) AS rn2
        ) tx ON tx.ztimestamp = t0.ztimestamp
WHERE tx.rn1=1 OR tx.rn2=1
        ;
```